# React + fetch: adding extra characters and backslashes to my url

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch

I have this code in React 17

```
useEffect(() => {
    getLocalJson('../json/login/login.json', props.headers)
      .then(resp => { 
          setFields(resp);
    });
}, [props.headers]);
```

And the `getLocalJson` method is in a different file:

```
export const getLocalJson = async (url, headers) => {
    console.log(url)
    const resp = await fetch(url, {'headers': headers});
    const json = await resp.json();
    return json;
}
```

However the call to load the local JSON file from the public folder is:

Request URL: http://localhost:3000/json/login/%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5C%5Cdx%5Cjson%5Clogin%5Clogin.json

Ths is the JSON

```
[
  {
    "order": 0,
    "systemName": "title",
    "friendlyName": "Login",
    "dataType": {
      "type": "TITLE"
    }
  },
  {
    "order": 1,
    "required": true,
    "systemName": "username",
    "friendlyName": "Username",
    "errorMsg": "Invalid username",
    "dataType": {
      "type": "TEXT"
    }
  },
  {
    "order": 2,
    "required": true,
    "systemName": "password",
    "friendlyName": "Password",
    "errorMsg": "Invalid password",
    "dataType": {
      "type": "PASSWORD"
    }
  },
  {
    "order": 3,
    "systemName": "title",
    "friendlyName": "Login",
    "dataType": {
      "type": "BUTTON",
      "submit": true
    }
  }
]
```

And it makes the call over and over and over

This exact code works on my ubuntu dev box, but is failing as abovw on my windows box

Comment: *"And it makes the call over and over and over"* - What does `setFields` do specifically?  What effects does it have on the overall state?  Does anything modify the URL?  Does anything cause the component to be re-rendered or re-loaded, or `props.headers` to be updated?

Comment: setFields is a useState hook, settings the fields var. Commenting this out has no effect. Nothing modifies the url, the  stirng is passed directly to fetch.

Comment: If removing it has no effect then it would seem likely to me that the issue may be outside of what we're looking at.  Is the URL of the application changing?  Is the entire component which hosts this `useEffect` being re-loaded due to something further up the component hierarchy?  Is this something you can replicate in isolation for us to observe, perhaps in a CodeSandbox or even here as a Stack Snippet?

Comment: It seems weird, especially because this exact code works on ubuntu chrome. It seems to have to do with headers, see comments below. There is nothing upstream this is the login form that is presented at the start of the single page app.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with the way you are passing down the headers, look into the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to have a better idea.

Comment: It seems to be related to that, but why woulf it work on ubuntu chrome and not windows chrome? When I change the headers on windows chrome, the errors go away but it says there is an error in the JSON when there is not

Comment: This may be because of the difference between the ways windows and ubuntu use to locate a file in the system. If I understand your problem correctly, using the fs module might remove the error and also make fetch requests consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Put your function in the body of your component where you're using useEffect and wrap it with useCallback like this:

```
const getLocalJson =  useCallback( async (url, headers) => {
    console.log(url)
    const resp = await fetch(url, {'headers': headers});
    const json = await resp.json();
    
    return json;
  },[])
```

Comment: I can't use hooks, this code is not in a react component.

Comment: This is why I told you to put it in the code of the component

Comment: But I want this code to be reusable, which is why is in a separate file.

Comment: then put the function in the depenedncies array [props.headers ,getLocalJson]

Comment: That does not resolve the problem that I cannot use the hook in the shared code that I am importing.